# How to make keyboard work like OSX System Wide Ubuntu 18?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, copy, paste

How can I, using Ubuntu 18, remap my keyboard `<ctrl>-c` to `<super>-c` and `<ctrl>-p` to `<super>-p`?

I've followed Gnome questions on AskUbuntu but the answers do not work for Ubuntu 18.`

Comment: I assume you’re using a regular keyboard, not a Macintosh keyboard, but it would be helpful to say (also if it’s a UK keyboard vs. US).

Comment: sure, I am using a regular keyboard.